# Access Android Module Classes From Core Module Classes in libgdx

Tags: java, android, module, libgdx, android-module

I was integrating my `(libgdx) core module` with `android module` to compile my whole project into one big project. However, at the end of this integration, I ran into a problem which I didn't think before.

I am not able to access the functions in the `android module` from the `core module`. However, I can access from android to core. I used the default `libgdx setup.jar` to create my libgdx project for android. I tried to include the `android module` as a dependency in the `core module` but that leads to an error stating `Error: Circular reference between projects: :android -> :core -> :android`. So I thought why not make another java module such that `another_module` depends on `core module` and then `android module` will depend on `another_module`. But doing this led to this error stating `Error:Module ':core:1.0' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar`. I tried making `another_module` as a `java library` but the error is the same.

Now I am sure that there is a solution for this. Maybe making an Interface somehow in `android module` that `core module` can access.

I am new to all this. Any suggestions, recommendations or a solution perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Well after tons of research I figured out a solution for my problem. We can solve this problem with the help of interfaces without touching the `Gradle` part. All we have to do is create an interface in the `core module` and then implement it in some class in the `android module` and then pass that class to the `core module` through `AndroidLauncher`.

For Detailed Details refer to [lib**GDX** on *Interfacing with platform specific code*](https://libgdx.com/wiki/app/interfacing-with-platform-specific-code)

I won't delete this post so that others who are also facing this problem can see this post and not waste a lot of their time on trying to fix `Gradle`.